# execjs runtime error and ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

rails g scaffold Home body:text

ran a simple scaffold and got this error:

```
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs.rb:2:in `require': /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
      name:        "Node.js (V8)",
           ^
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
      name:        "JavaScriptCore",
           ^
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
      name:        "SpiderMonkey",
           ^
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:42: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
      name:        "JScript",
           ^
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:42: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
/home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs.rb:2
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
        from /home/tailwind/cms/config/application.rb:7
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
        from /home/tailwind/cms/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:24
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

ruby version 1.8.7
rails versin 3.2.11

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

gem "rake"

gem "ruby"

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'

#gem 'json'
gem 'json','~>1.7.6'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'




  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'execjs'

gem 'therubyracer'

#gem 'paperclip'

gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4.3"

gem 'cocaine'

gem 'rmagick'

gem "mini_magick"

gem 'mail'

gem "cancan"
gem 'fancybox-rails'


gem 'authlogic','~>3.2.0'

gem 'RedCloth', '4.2.2'

gem "rails3-generators"




gem 'carrierwave', '>= 0.5.3'

gem 'nested_form'
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem so a point in the right direction would be great maybe I need the right gem for exec.js to run ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version of exec-js requires Ruby 1.9 or greater, as it uses the new hash syntax. You'll have to downgrade exec-js, or upgrade your Ruby.

Since Ruby 1.8.7 [reached end-of-life](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/) almost a year ago, the correct answer would be to upgrade Ruby.

Comment: I downgraded exec-js to 2.0.0 and it's not running fine, thank you Meagar!

Comment: I had to use 'execjs' instead of 'exec-js'

Comment: @GregKrsak That's fine, but that is unrelated to the problem described in the question.

Comment: That's why I put is as a comment to your answer-- just in case someone (me) tries your suggestion and it doesn't quite work, I can show what did work for me.